How to pass more arguments to snackbar in jetpack compose
I want to pass 3 arguments to my custom snackbar, but snackstate.showSnackbar() takes only one argument which is message - a string. What is a proper way to pass more arguments to snackbar? I've already made a workaround using Gson.toJson() and Gson.fromJson() but it doesn't seem the best option.



Have you tried extending the SnackbarHostState class and overriding showSnackbar?
